# Trying to display the value of my variable in go

Tags: go

I'm learning go today and I can't understand why %v don't work.

First of all, my version of go is 1.17.6.

Then, here is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        x := 16
        fmt.Println("%v", x)
}
```

Here the output:

```
%v 16
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `fmt.Printf` instead of Println. In the `fmt` package only the functions whose name ends with the letter `f` support formatting.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
fmt.Printf("%v", x)
```

To also add a line after printing this, you can use:

```
fmt.Printf("%v\n", x)
```